# Liveness-Probe of one pod via another

Tags: kubernetes, probe

On my Kubernetes Setup, I have 2 pods - A (via deployment) and B(via DS).
Pod B is somehow dependent on Pod A being fully started through. I would now like to set an HTTP Liveness-Probe in Pods B, to restart POD B if health check via POD A fails. Restarting works fine if I put the External IP of my POD A's service in the host. The issue is in resolving DNS name in the host.

It works if I set it like this:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    host: <POD_A_SERVICE_EXTERNAL_IP_HERE>
    path: /health
    port: 8000
```

Fails if I set it like this:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    host: auth
    path: /health
    port: 8000
```

Failed with following error message:

> ```sh
> Liveness probe failed: Get http://auth:8000/health: dial tcp: lookup auth on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
> ```

ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Is the following line on the above page true for HTTP Probes as well?
"you can not use a service name in the host parameter since the kubelet is unable to resolve it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct , DNS doesn't work for liveness probes, the kubelet network space cannot basically resolve any in-cluster DNS.

You can consider putting both of your services in a single pod as sidecars. This way they would share the same address space if one container fails then the whole pod is restarted.

Another option is to create an [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/)  for your pods/application and basically have it check the liveness through the in-cluster DNS for both pods separately and restart the pods through the Kubernetes API.

You can also just create your own script in a pod that just calls [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) to check for a `200 OK` and `kubectl` to restart your pod if you get something else.

Note that for the 2 options above you need to make sure that Coredns is stable and solid otherwise your health checks might fail to make your services have potential downtime.

✌️☮️

Comment: Nope that might make it more complicated or land me where I started off. I think putting a VIP as a variable while deployment will work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the DNS constraint specific to liveness probes or to all the probes? I'm trying to do something similar where I have a multi-Helm chart integration test application, and I want my tester to "wait for" the backend API Helm deployment to be ready, so was hoping to add a probe in the tester that pings an endpoint exposed by the backend API...